# Finding words following a certain phrase, up until a different phrase, using a text file

Tags: python

Is there a way to find a certain phrase, then use the following information (only after it) as an output, but only up until a different specified phrase? sorry if its confusing!

Comment: You could try regular expressions with lookahead and lookbehind, or just use a loop and some `find` statements. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do you mean finding the words between the phrases?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
string = "Is there a way to find a certain phrase, " \
         "then use the following information (only after it) " \
         "as an output, but only up until a different " \
         "specified phrase? sorry if its confusing!"
first_phrase = "certain phrase"
second_phrase = "a different specified phrase"

intermediate = (string[string.find(first_phrase)+len(first_phrase):])
final = intermediate[0:intermediate.find(second_phrase)]

print final
```

The final result is:

```
, then use the following information (only after it) as an output, but only up until
```

Which is what you wanted. You may refactor the code to get rid of intermediate variables, but I wanted to make it readable.